# Unable to debug remote docker node.js app from WebStorm

Tags: node.js, docker, intellij-idea, webstorm, remote-debugging

I am trying to attach a remote debugger to a node.js app running in docker from within WebStorm but am unable to do. I can successfully run docker app from IDE but cannot debug it.

I am following this guide to setup remote interpreter :
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#node_debugging_overview

My docker-compose.yaml looks something like this:

```
ports:
  - 8080:8080
  - 9229:9229

command: [ "npm", "run","debug" ]
```

package.json has debug script defined like :

```
"debug":"node --inspect-brk"
```

If someone has set this up can you please suggest what am I not doing correct ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind to all interfaces in container

```
--inspect=0.0.0.0
```

or

```
--inspect-brk=0.0.0.0
```

[Command-line options](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#command-line-options)

However this is dangerous in production environments 
[Exposing the debug port publicly is unsafe](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#exposing-the-debug-port-publicly-is-unsafe)

Comment: Thank You for all your replies :

So this is what my debug script looks like now: 

"develop": "NODE_ENV=development node -- --inspect=0.0.0.0:8090 ./baseFille.js"


Another weird thing is when i send a curl Request to port 8090 (which is suppose to be my debugger port) i don't get any response.
Can that be the issue why i cannot debug?

Answer (score 1):

Using Docker Compose as Node.js remote interpreter is not currently supported, see [WEB-23404](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23404).
So you need using [Attach to Node.js/Chrome](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.3/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html) run configuration to attach to your node.js app running in docker:

[image]

But, as node binds to localhost by default and thus can't be accessed from outside, you need changing your npm script to `"debug":"node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229"`, as it's mentioned in *@ponury-kostek* answer

Comment: So i tried using this but for some reason it breaks up abruptly and comes out. Gives a error message with 'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint'.

Comment: doesn't look related to debugging. see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277 for some hints